# Locate file downloaded to the browser

Tags: google-chrome, download, temp

I download pdf files from a server. However, I first access the file by clicking on the link where the file is located on the remote server, which brings it into my browser. I understand that I can then 'Save As' and I can save this file shown in my browser to a specific location on my PC. But the file has already been downloaded to my computer (somewhere?). After the file is downloaded to the browser, I want to find out the size of the file before I take the next step in my process. If I can locate the temp (?) file where it is located on my PC after the pdf is loaded in the browser I can find the size.

I have checked every temp folder on my PC I can find immediately after I bring the pdf into the browser, but I am not able to find it.

I also have done a search on my PC for every file stored on my PC whatever it is and nothing shows up. The file coming into the browser resolves as a PDF file and is (in this one example) ~82MB in size, and the fact it takes so long to render in my browser means the browser is consuming ~82MB of data before it renders on my screen. But all the files I find in the time this file was downloaded to the browser nothing comes even close to 82MB

Where are these files going on my PC that are 'downloaded' to the browser but not yet 'saved as'?

Comment: blech, that is what I suspected ... I'll have to figure out a different approach to getting a 'preview' of filesize -